# A software solution to a logic puzzle

Tags: prolog, logic

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217248/which-answer-in-this-list-is-the-correct-answer-to-this-question) I found a charming, if fairly easy logic problem:

> Which answer in this list is the correct answer to *this* question?
>
> 1. All of the below.
> 2. None of the below.
> 3. All of the above.
> 4. One of the above.
> 5. None of the above.
> 6. None of the above.

It would be fairly easy to re-write these propositions as statements in some programing language:

```
def p1 = p2 && p3 && p4 && p5 && p6
def p2 = !p3 && !p4 && !p5 && !p6
def p3 = p1 && p2
```

and so on.  What's more difficult is to actually run such a program without getting into an infinite loop.

Is there a language or library (or something) that solve this more-or-less natively?  I'm thinking Prolog, because all I know about Prolog is it's used for solving "problems like this".

What would the code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed trivial to solve such logic puzzles with **Prolog**.

For example, one approach is to use **CLP(B)**, which stands for Constraint Logic Programming over **Boolean** variables and has its own tag, [clpb](/questions/tagged/clpb).

Several Prolog systems ship with a CLP(B) solver. SICStus Prolog is one very prominent example.

The core idea of such an approach is to formulate the task as a **constraint satisfaction problem** (CSP) over Boolean variables.

In this concrete case, we can for example use the **propositional variables** A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, ..., A<sub>6</sub> to represent the different ways to answer the question. Each answer relates one of these variables to several others, reflecting what the answer states about other answers.

Using SICStus Prolog, a declarative *description* of what each answer means could look like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).

solution([A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6]) :-
        sat(A1 =:= A2*A3*A4*A5*A6),
        sat(A2 =:= ~(A2+A3+A4+A5+A6)),
        sat(A3 =:= A1*A2),
        sat(A4 =:= card([1],[A1,A2,A3])),
        sat(A5 =:= ~(A1+A2+A3+A4)),
        sat(A6 =:= ~(A1+A2+A3+A4+A5)).
```

From the following query, we see that only **one** answer is logically admissible subject to these constraints:

```
?- solution(Vs).
Vs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].
```

Thus, **answer 5** is the only one that can be chosen while keeping all statements consistent.

An **infinite loop** *cannot arise* in such a formulation, since *each* of the individual constraints always *terminates*, and the whole program consists only of a sequence of such constraints.

The constraint solver has *automatically* deduced the single admissible solution, using a process called constraint **propagation**.

Comment: If "card" means cardinality, then you have interpreted (4) to mean "exactly one of the above".  The answer doesn't change if you interpret it as "at least one of the above".

Comment: Yes, it's true, I have interpreted this as "*exactly* one of the above". To interpret it as "at least one of the above, please change `[1]` to `[1,2,3]`  in the `card/2` expression, which indeed denotes cardinality. More precisely, `card(Ls, Exprs)` is true *iff* the number of *true* expressions in `Exprs` is a member of the list `Ls` of integers or integer pairs denoting *ranges* of integers. Therefore, instead of `[1,2,3]`, you can equivalently use `[1-3]`. The solution stays exactly the same.